# How do I make donation goal percent bar update on submit?

Tags: php, mysql, submit

I have a script that displays a percentage bar and I plan on using it for our donation goals so users can see how much more money we need in a specific month.  This is the code currently:

```
<style>
.percentbar { background:#CCCCCC; border:1px solid #666666; height:25px; }
.percentbar div { background: #28B8C0; height: 25px; border-right:1px solid black }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include("config.php");
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM donationgoal");
    while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
        if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
    $add = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['add']);
            $total = $info['total'] + $add;
        }
    mysql_query("UPDATE donationgoal SET total = ".$total." ");
            $value = $info['total'];
    }

        echo $value;

// Testing numbers. Replace with your own.
$max = 100;
$scale = 2.0;

// Get Percentage out of 100
if ( !empty($max) ) { $percent = ($value * 100) / $max; } 
else { $percent = 0; }

// Limit to 100 percent (if more than the max is allowed)
if ( $percent > 100 ) { $percent = 100; } 
?>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="add" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<div class="percentbar" style="width:<?php echo round(100 * $scale); ?>px;">
  <div style="width:<?php echo round($percent * $scale); ?>px;"></div>
</div>
Percentage: <?php echo $percent; ?>%
</body>
```

Now this works completely fine (updates the table perfectly) however, after the page refreshes after the submit, the bar doesn't change.  The only way it will change is if I manually refresh the page after I already submitted the form.  Is there a way to make it so after the initial submit the bar will update?

Answer (score 0):

that's because your `insert` query is after your `select` query, you have to insert the new record before getting the data from `mysql`
your code would be like this:

```
<style>
.percentbar { background:#CCCCCC; border:1px solid #666666; height:25px; }
.percentbar div { background: #28B8C0; height: 25px; border-right:1px solid black }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include("config.php");
if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
    $add = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['add']);
    mysql_query("UPDATE donationgoal SET `total` = `total` + ".$add." ");
}
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM donationgoal");
    while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
            $value = $info['total'];
    }
        echo $value;

// Testing numbers. Replace with your own.
$max = 100;
$scale = 2.0;

// Get Percentage out of 100
if ( !empty($max) ) { $percent = ($value * 100) / $max; } 
else { $percent = 0; }

// Limit to 100 percent (if more than the max is allowed)
if ( $percent > 100 ) { $percent = 100; } 
?>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="add" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<div class="percentbar" style="width:<?php echo round(100 * $scale); ?>px;">
  <div style="width:<?php echo round($percent * $scale); ?>px;"></div>
</div>
Percentage: <?php echo $percent; ?>%
</body>
```

**BTW:** Please Please Please stop using mysql and use `mysqli` instead.

Comment: Ahh I see, I got it working buy putting another select query after the update query.  Would that be the most efficient way to do that?

Comment: Oooh I like that a lot better than what I did lol.  Thanks I appreciate it

Comment: you don't have to care about efficiency as much as you have to care about security reliability and you can achieve both by using `mysqli` and not including too many queries in your code